# ‘The front part of the car was damaged’

Tags: word-usage

> The front part of the car was damaged.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/part

I think a part means a piece, a separate thing, and the car was not divided, but how can ‘a part of the car’ be valid? Does ‘part’ mean the other thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The front of the car was damaged

would be normal English. However if you take the car as being a whole piece and only a part is damaged, in this case the front. Then technically it is correct *"The front part of the car was damaged"*; even it is not commonly spoken of in this manner. Part is not necessarily a separate piece of something.

> In parts of Canada, French is the first language

To take this further it it is not unusual to refer to a part of an object, albeit an individual component or an area of something.

> Will the car start? No some part is damaged, Dad is fixing it now.

> Someone hit us in the carpark and part of the bumper is damaged.

---

**part**; noun (SOME); some but not all of a thing:

Example

> Part of my steak isn't cooked properly. Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/part)

**part;** noun (SEPARATE PIECE); a separate piece of something, or a piece that combines with other pieces to form the whole of something